# c++ where to put constant variables private to cc file if I need them for testing

Tags: c++, testing, namespaces, constants

My header file looks like this:

```
// method.h
class Class {
    public:
        string Method(const int number);
};
```

My cc file looks like this

```
// method.cc
#include "method.h"

namespace {
    const char kImportantString[] = "Very long and important string";
}

string Class::Method(const int number) {
    [... computation which depends on kImportantString ...] 
    return some_string;
}
```

Now for some inputs the `Method()` should return `kImportantString`,
but for other inputs it must not return `kImportantString`

Therefore, I would like to create a test file, which would look like this:

```
// method_test.cc
#include "method.h"

void Test() {
    assert(Method(1) == kImportantString);  // kImportantString is not visible
    assert(Method(2) != kImportantString);  // in this file, how to fix this?
}
```

But currently the problem is that `kImportantString` is not within the scope of `method_test.cc` file.

- Adding `kImportantString` to `method.h` is not ideal, as it is not needed inside the header file.
- Creating a separate file "utils.h" and putting just one string there seems like an overkill (although might be the best option).
- Copying `kImportantString` into a test file is not ideal, because the string is quite long, and later someone might accidentally change it in one file, but not the other.

Hence, my question is:

**What's the best way to make kImportantString be visible in the test file, and be invisible in as many other places as possible?**

Comment: Maybe make it a static, private member of the class and then befriend `void Test()`.

Comment: There is almost no reason for an argument type to be `const int` as in your example. `int`s are passed by value, so the original value *cannot* be changed by the function anyway.

Comment: I think there may be an argument that says you should not have access to `kImportantString` in the test file. The test file should contain its *own* *reference string* and it is a bug if the program fails to reproduce it for any reason (maybe the programmer made a typo when typing in the value of `kImportantString`?).

Comment: @Dan Roche, but const prevents modifying argument inside the function, and hence is more readable.

Comment: @Galik, I like your point. So would you say that copying string into the test file (second option) is reasonable?

Comment: You mean the *third* option? That sounds reasonable to me for the very reason you suggest it may not be ideal - because later someone may change it in one file but not the other. It is exactly that kind of potential error that you want to be able to detect and if the test shares the same text as the software being tested a corruption/accidental modification to the text would go undetected. If the text is changed *intentionally* in one file but not the other then that will be caught (and resolved) when the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an `extern` declaration in the header file, like

```
extern const char kImportantString[];
```

And then leave the actual definition in the `.c` file. This would allow the test program to access the string without actually having to copy the whole thing into the header.

If you want to leave it out of the header entirely, but not to copy it into the test file, you could also just make a special header file like `kImportantString.h` and put the `extern` declaration in there.

Another option would be to compute a *hash* of the string in the test file, and just compare the hashes. But this might be more trouble than it's worth.